# Manga about "war between nations, and special individuals with elemental tattoos"

Tags: story-identification, manga

Many years ago, I read a comic/graphic novel/manga, and the main theme was about war in a fantasy world (think of *Final Fantasy*, maybe). I believe the war was between multiple parties (i.e. more than 2), but I only remember that one of the parties was an established colony with blonde hair and armor, and another party/tribe had darker skin and rode big birds(?).

In addition, there was a special feature that one person from each tribe had... they all had some tattoo representing some element. I cannot remember if it meant they had control over the elements, or if it had some other greater meaning.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy. Please make sure you've checked out the [tour], read [ask] (and possibly [answer]), as well as the [Story-ID guidelines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). What language did you read it in? Where were you when you read it? Medium? Etc. What do you mean by 'many years ago' - do you a date that's any more specific? Any detail helps, no matter how small it may seem!

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the manga adaptation of Suikoden 3. Its run went from 2002-2006 and follows the events of the game.

It does begin with a dark skinned character and I do believe he rides a griffon (its been a long time since I've read it). He has tattoo on one of his hands which represents the fire element.

I've only read part of it but I remember it being very focus on war and army stratgy.

Here's the cover of the first book:
[image]